# How to use files outside of cypress that use an alias

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have an app that uses an alias in a typescript config that looks like:

```
app/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  ...,
}
```

And then in my cypress folder I am extending this tsconfig:

```
cypress/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../app/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "@testing-library/cypress"],
  },
  "include": ["../node_modules/cypress", "**/*.ts"]
}
```

But when I try to import something in a file that has an alias I get the error. For example in my `cypress/support` file I import a function from `app/utils` that imports a type from `~/graphql` (`~/graphql` == `app/graphql`).

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/graphql' in '/Users/my-user/my-project/app/utils' resolve '~/graphql' in '/Users/my-user/my-project/app/utils'
```

I can see in the logs it is looking in the wrong places:

```
[/Users/my-user/my-project/app/utils/node_modules]
[/Users/my-user/my-project/app/node_modules]
[/Users/my-user/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
```

It almost had it here `/Users/my-user/my-project/app/utils/node_modules` but for some reason was looking for a `node_modules` folder?

How can I set up my cypress config to respect the paths in my `app/tsconfig`? I have tried adding the below variations to my `cypress/tsconfig` but nothing seems to work.

```
cypress/tsconfig.json
"paths": { "~/*": ["*"] }
"paths": { "~/*": ["../app/*"] }
"paths": { "~/*": ["../*"] }
```